# В третий раз стал отцом

Tags: семантика

Есть такое расхожее выражение **"Во второй/третий раз стал отцом/лауреатом/депутатом/чемпионом"**. Смысл его понятен, двусмысленность возникает

Ведь третий раз **стать** Иксом можно только с перерывом, когда ты этим Иксом не был. И если по отношению к чемпиону это еще более или менее оправдано (сегодня ты, завтра другой, потом снова ты...), то с отцовством как-то не прокатывает. Неужели "отцовство" даётся не навечно, независимо даже от судьбы ребенка (Боже, избави!)?!

**Насколько выражение верно вообще и применительно к отцу и чемпиону (с учетом сказанного) в частности?**

Ранее более популярный вариант "стал дважды отцом/президентом" менее режет слух, но решает проблему лишь частично, применительно у чемпиону, но никак не к отцу. "Дважды Герой" - это ведь тоже образчик советского канцеляризма, до того, дважды одним орденом никогда не награждали, для повторного награждения существовали степени. А "отец"-то почему дважды?

Вот пример только одного парадокса, основанного на этом вольном использовании порядковых номеров "отцовства". Отец двойняшек, а потом еще одного ребенка - от в третий раз отцом становится? А если во второй, то он трижды ли отец?!

Comment: Для человека, употребляющего слово "не прокатывает", Вас волнуют слишком тонкие языковые вопросы.

Comment: @Igor Я еще много слов знаю. По сути можете что-нибудь добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Не вижу ничего плохого: это из области удобных лаконизмов. Стать отцом - понятие относительное: можно стать им сначала по отношению к одному ребёнку, а затем повторить действие "становления" по отношению к другому. При этом можно не только дважды "*стать* отцом", но и *быть* "дважды или четырежды отцом" - иными словами, отцом по отношению к соотв. количеству детей (но коротко и информативно). "*Дважды герой*" - человек, дважды удостоенный гос. награды, в наименовании которой есть слово "герой"; это краткое условное наименование, которое всеми понимается однозначно.

Куда порой заводят поиски строго буквального смысла, можно проиллюстрировать курьёзным случаем из другого форума (там некто с увлечением взялся за одну из статей Конституции и зарапортовался):
http://forum.lingvo.ru/actualthread.aspx?tid=139535